# spring compensating.support.DefaultCompensatingTransactionOperationManager commit is failing on recursive delete

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-transactions, spring-ldap

I am using spring's compensating transaction manager for ldap. I am using `DefaultTempEntryRenamingStrategy`.
It does a in place soft delete by renaming the entities (hence dn ) to `<original_name>_temp` and then while committing the traction actually go and delete if it’s successful or roll back otherwise. The problem is it’s not able to do the actual delete recursively for all the subtree nodes.

**Reason:**
When it’s doing soft delete it’s actually modifying the dn of the object. and Path is changed now. but when it’s actually going to delete recursively the leaf nodes it’s not using the updated Dn’s but the old ones.

And it’s searching for : remaining name `*'cn=1157718410FB13@example.com_temp,ou=People,o=122C91C0C62A83,o=Customers'*`
But actually it should be searching for `*'cn=1157718410FB13@example.com_temp,ou=People,o=122C91C0C62A83**_temp**,o=Customers’*`

I am not sure If there is some configuration I have to do to for recursive delete or this is a bug. Any suggestions welcome I am yet to explore the other strategy which is DifferentSubtreeTempEntryRenamingStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like a bug, but I must admit that I wouldn't quite know how to fix it using the `DefaultTempEntryRenamingStrategy`.

I would expect it to work as expected using the `DifferentSubtreeTempEntryRenamingStrategy` (which is actually the preferred strategy anyway - the reason why it's not the default is that it requires a little more work, in particular you need to make sure that there is a place in the LDAP tree where the strategy can place the entries).